# How to remotely log user out of application?

Tags: windows-7, windows, domain

My problem is this: we are running an application that is licensed for only one user at a time on a given machine.  If as an admin I remote into a computer running this software, knocking a user off the machine, that user is still logged into the application when I log into Windows.  My workaround is to start task manager, click processes > 'show processes from all users' then click users, right click the other guy and select log off.  This always works but it drives me nuts to have to do it.  Is there a way to set these computers up so my logging someone off Windows also logs them off any applications?

BTW, this is occurring on Windows 7 Enterprise computers.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just write a script that will close the process when a user logs in?

Comment: I would just write a script that kills the process, create a shortcut to `C:\Users\Default\Desktop` and teach my users to run it if they need the software. Or change the software shortcut to run the script as well before the application starts.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624921/how-to-stop-a-process-automatically-via-a-batch-script